# lenovo 330s Ryzen error installing ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi, lenovo, amd-graphics

When i try to install ubuntu the screen freeze in black, but i could installed it with "noapic" and "idle=nowait", it instaled and, but when i try to open ubuntu it doesn´t open, the screen freeze in purple.i did the partition before install and it´s have uefi

Answer (score 0):

For the same reasons you needed to add noapic and idle=nowait to the boot options of your installation media, you need to add the same boot options in the boot file that has been written on your hard drive during installation.

For this you can boot on your live isb and follow instructions that you will easilly find on internet

Comment: I did that, but when i select to open ubuntu, the screen goes purple and keeps there